how to set env in docker image
I want to set the env MALLOC_CONF=prof:true in docker image. I have tried like this:
ENV MALLOC_CONF=prof:true

also tried:
RUN export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true

then login into the docker image and check env like this(the docker image was running in kubernetes as deployment):
env|grep "MALLOC_CONF"

both did not found the MALLOC_CONF environment. This is the docker file:
ARG BASE_IMAGE=dolphinjiang/rust-musl-builder:1.78.0
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS builder
ADD --chown=rust:rust . ./
RUN git clone --depth 1 --branch 91d69b73e2fc9c65953c04debe0f06fbd1e51299 https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex.git
RUN cd synctex && gcc -c -fPIC *.c && gcc -shared *.o -o libsynctex_parser.so -lz
RUN cp libsynctex_parser.so ../src/so/
RUN RUSTFLAGS='-L ./src/so' cargo build --release

FROM alpine:3.18.2
LABEL maintainer="jiangtingqiang@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ENV MALLOC_CONF=prof:true
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/settings.toml /app
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/src/so/libsynctex_parser.so /app
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/src/so/libsynctex_parser.so /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/log4rs.yaml /app
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/texhub-server /app/
RUN apk update && apk add curl websocat zlib zlib-dev openssl-dev openssl tzdata musl-locales
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN echo 'export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8' >> /etc/profile.d/locale.sh && \
  sed -i 's|LANG=C.UTF-8|LANG=en_GB.UTF-8|' /etc/profile.d/locale.sh
RUN export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true
CMD ["./texhub-server"]

Am I missing something? what should I do to set the image environmnet variable?

The RUN only happens during the docker build phase and then immediately exits. It only sets the variable in a temporary shell which ceases to exist when RUN finishes. But your ENV should work.

How exactly are you building the image and checking the variable value?  RUN export is a no-op but the ENV syntax you show should work fine.

The ENV directive is the right way to do that.
Here is a minimal reproducible example from your case, same base image. Maybe you should try quoting the string -- even if in my example both syntaxes work.
FROM alpine:3.18.2

ENV MALLOC_CONF="prof:true"

And we can see that it works as expected.
docker run --rm rust-test sh -c 'env | grep MALLOC'
MALLOC_CONF=prof:true


I will try what you said later. @Romain
